# What is happening in this go concurrency example?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am on the concurrency example here: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

This is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x + y
        case <- quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<- c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

There is quite a bit about this that is confusing to me and the tour itself doesn't say much about it. It says that select will wait on communication operations but I don't really get how that applies to the function that it sends to a goroutine before calling `fibonacci`. `fmt.Println` is being sent the channel `c`, but I just don't see why or how this makes any sense...

I have so many questions about this, I am hoping that everything falls into place after understanding the first part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code example the goroutine is launched, and runs until it hits `fmt.Println(<- c)` where it is printing the values it receives from `c`. At this point in time `i == 0` we're in the first iteration. Meanwhile, since this is running in a goroutine, main has continued execution and called `fibonacci` passing it the `c` and `quit` channels. The `fibonacci` function is sitting in an 'infinite' select, meaning you will never get out of this without explicitly calling `return` as it does when it receives from the `quit` channel.

So back in main, where you invoked the goroutine, it blocks until receiving from the channel, `fibonacci` begins executing and sending on that channel, providing the next number in the `fibonacci` sequence until that loop terminates (when `i == 10`) at which point the code there moves down to `quit <- 0` where is sends on the quit channel. Since you're in an infinite select over there in `fibonacci` it will always execute the next available case, it cannot continue sending on `c` because that channel is not buffered, it only allows one item and is full, instead it moves in the `quit` case statement because it has received something on the `quit` channel, at which point it prints `quit` and returns.

Hope that helps. Some of the language may not be 100% accurate. Really just trying to illustrate how this control flow works. I think actually, the select waits until the goroutine in main can receive at which point it goes into the `c <- x` statement and sends. You can observe this by trying to read an item out of the channel after everything is done, which causes a panic. In effect they're both waiting for one another, you can't send on a full channel and if you just read off it without any other control flow (like a select) then you will block until there is something there to receive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helps with the first part, but now I am confused about the select statement, is it choosing the `c <- x` part because the goroutine "opens" the channel and then the switch statement reads something like `if x can send to c; do...`? If I am correct, then how can I interpret the second case...?

Comment: @deltaskelta yep, that's the basic idea. Think of it like a switch where it executes the first condition that is met. You're receiving from the `quit` channel so something sending on `quit` will put you in that case, you're sending on `c` so something having read off `c` will open it up for another write causing you to go into that case.